# Error in DDL creation in Hive using RegexSerDe

Tags: regex, hadoop, hive

I am having data with delimiters as ",|".

I have created the hive DDL as follows :

```
      CREATE TABLE player_profile
      (
       player_id BIGINT COMMENT 'Player Profile Identifier', 
       change_ts STRING COMMENT 'Change Datetime', 
       child_birth_year INT COMMENT 'Child Birth Year', 
       country STRING COMMENT 'Country Code', 
      )
      ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
      WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ('input.regex'='^(\\d+),\\|(.*),\\|(\\d+),\\|(.*)$')
      STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'
      OUTPUTFORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat';
```

I am getting the flowing error while deploying this ddl.

```
 FAILED: Error in metadata: java.lang.RuntimeException: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe only accepts string columns, but column[0] named player_id has type bigint)
 FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.DDLTask
```

Is it an issue with the regex expression i gave ? If so what is the regex in this case.

Does Hive(0.11) regex serde support BIGINT ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`RegexSerDe` explicitly checks if all columns are strings. See [RegexSerDe.java](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hive/trunk/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java?revision=1461235&view=markup#l112)

You could change all columns to strings, and then cast between int and string when you are querying the data.

Answer (score 0):

As the problem stated in your exception:

```
RegexSerDe only accepts string columns, but column[0] named player_id has type bigint
```

RegexSerDe doesn't support bigint only strings.

Have you tried changing:

```
player_id BIGINT COMMENT
```

By:

```
player_id STRING COMMENT
```

To check if it solves your issue?

You can see the [RegexSerDe.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/hive/tags/release-0.10.0/contrib/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/contrib/serde2/RegexSerDe.java) source code mention it:

```
// All columns have to be of type STRING.
for (int c = 0; c < numColumns; c++) {
  if (!columnTypes.get(c).equals(TypeInfoFactory.stringTypeInfo)) {
    throw new SerDeException(getClass().getName()
        + " only accepts string columns, but column[" + c + "] named "
        + columnNames.get(c) + " has type " + columnTypes.get(c));
  }
}
```

As you can see that's the error you are getting. Hope to help.